# Python: how to increment a ctypes POINTER instance

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

Assume `p = ctypes.cast("foo", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))`.

Thus, we have `p.contents.value == "f"`.

How can I directly access and manipulate (e.g. increment) the pointer? E.g. like `(p + 1).contents.value == "o"`.

Comment: This is not always such a hot idea in C; to see someone want to apply it to Python scares me a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use indexing:

```
>>> p = ctypes.cast("foo", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))
>>> p[0]
'f'
>>> p[1]
'o'
>>> p[3]
'\x00'
```

Have a look at [ctypes documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-pointers) to find out more about using pointers.

**UPDATE**: It seems that it's not what you need. Let's, then, try another approach: first cast the pointer to void, increment it and then cast it back to LP_c_char:

```
In [93]: p = ctypes.cast("foo", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))

In [94]: void_p = ctypes.cast(p, ctypes.c_voidp).value+1

In [95]: p = ctypes.cast(void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))

In [96]: p.contents
Out[96]: c_char('o')
```

Maybe it's not elegant but it works.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I really want to modify/increment `p`. If `p` would be a `c_void_p`, I could do `p.value += 1`.

Answer (score 5):

After getting back to this, I figured out that @Michał Bentkowski 's answer was still not enough for me because it didn't modified the original pointer.

This is my current solution:

```
a = ctypes.cast("foo", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))
aPtr = ctypes.cast(ctypes.pointer(a), ctypes.POINTER(c_void_p))
aPtr.contents.value += ctypes.sizeof(a._type_)

print a.contents
```